# Service account secret is not listed. How to fix it?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have used `kubectl create serviceaccount sa1` to create service account. Then I used `kubectl get serviceaccount sa1 -oyaml` command to get service account info. But it returns as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-05-16T08:03:50Z"
  name: sa1
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "19651"
  uid: fdddacba-be9d-4e77-a849-95ca243781cc
```

I need to get,

```
secrets:
- name: <secret>
```

part. but it doesn't return secrets. How to fix it?

Comment: Are you using Kubernetes 1.24?  I believe [that doesn't create the secret automatically](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.24.md#urgent-upgrade-notes) any more, and you need to [manually create it](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#service-account-token-secrets).

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes I'm using 1.24

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In Kubernetes 1.24, ServiceAccount token secrets are no longer automatically generated.  See ["Urgent Upgrade Notes" in the 1.24 changelog file](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.24.md#urgent-upgrade-notes):

> The `LegacyServiceAccountTokenNoAutoGeneration` feature gate is beta, and enabled by default. When enabled, Secret API objects containing service account tokens are no longer auto-generated for every ServiceAccount. Use the [TokenRequest](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/authentication-resources/token-request-v1/) API to acquire service account tokens, or if a non-expiring token is required, create a Secret API object for the token controller to populate with a service account token by following this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#service-account-token-secrets). ([#108309](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/108309), [@zshihang](https://github.com/zshihang))

This means, in Kubernetes 1.24, you need to [manually create the Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#service-account-token-secrets); the `token` key in the `data` field will be automatically set for you.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: sa1-token
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: sa1
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

Since you're manually creating the Secret, you know its `name:` and don't need to look it up in the ServiceAccount object.

This approach should work fine in earlier versions of Kubernetes too.

Comment: Correct, that approach works in all versions. Explicitly creating a secret if you need one is the recommended approach in all versions. The `.secrets` field is explicitly for enumerating secrets to be mounted into pods running as the service account, and there is no guarantee the first item in that list is a token secret.

Comment: After creating manual token for service account, how to authenticate further in Azure dev ops service connections ?

Comment: Someone simply forgot to update the documentation. [service-account-tokens](https://v1-24.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens) - it shows automatic secret creation when creating a serviceaccount

Comment: Don't forget the double quotes for the service-account.name should be `kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "sa1"`

Comment: That's not required.  Single quotes, double quotes, and no quotes will all produce an identical YAML document here.

Comment: for me this only worked when also setting a namespace

Answer (score 11):

I too struggled for a while with this, but ultimately I was able to get a temporary token of login using the

`kubectl create token [serviceaccount-name]`.

Still a newbie in this!!

Answer (score -1):

If any of the above solutions didn't worked, try this.

Go to Projects >> Project settings >> Service connections >> New service connection >> Kubernetes >> select the authentication method as KubeConfig and for the KubeConfig file,

Open AKS in azure portal

Open cloud shell or the Azure CLI

Run the following commands

az account set --subscription {subscription ID}

az aks get-credentials --resource-group {resource group name} --name {AKS-name} --admin

you will get a path to the kubeconfig file

cat /home/****/.kube/config

copy everything and paste in azure devops kubernetes service connection. Click on Accept untrusted certificates and Grant access permission to all pipelines. Give a service connection name and click verify.