# Cant create k8s dashboard service account

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard, k8s-serviceaccount

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTesI.png)

I followed this tutorial https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md
However, after finished all steps, i stll cant see any account while using kubectl get secreats command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be using below command to list the service accounts

```
kubectl get sa -n <namespace>
```

Comment: Thx!But there is no tokens in service account.

Comment: It appears like from1.24 version service account secret is not automatically generated. it should be manually created. Follow the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256006/service-account-secret-is-not-listed-how-to-fix-it