# Create access token for native Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create service account for native Kubernetes cluster so that I can send API calls:

```
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ kubectl create serviceaccount user1
serviceaccount/user1 created
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ kubectl create clusterrole nodeaccessrole --verb=get --verb=list --verb=watch --resource=nodes
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nodeaccessrole created
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding nodeaccessrolebinding --serviceaccount=default:user1 --clusterrole=nodeaccessrole
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/nodeaccessrolebinding created
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$ kubectl get serviceaccount user1
NAME    SECRETS   AGE
user1   0         7m15s
kubernetes@kubernetes1:~$
```

Do you know how I can get the token?

***SOLUTION for v1.25.1:***

```
kubectl create sa cicd

kubectl get sa,secret


cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cicd
spec:
  serviceAccount: cicd
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: cicd
EOF




kubectl exec cicd -- cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo

kubectl exec cicd cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo


kubectl create token cicd

kubectl create token cicd --duration=999999h



cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: cicd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "cicd"
EOF



kubectl get sa,secret

kubectl  describe secret cicd

kubectl   describe sa cicd

kubectl   get sa cicd -oyaml

kubectl   get sa,secret
```

One thing is not clear:

```
kubectl exec cicd -- cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo
    
kubectl exec cicd cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo
```

should I use '--' into the above commands?

Comment: Kubernetes 1.24?

Comment: I use v1.25.1. - the latest stable installed on Ubuntu 22.04 TLS

Comment: In recent versions of Kubernetes, tokens are not generated automatically for ServiceAccounts. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256006/service-account-secret-is-not-listed-how-to-fix-it for.

Comment: I managed to create a user and token. Please see the last question.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Please do not edit to add additional questions to an existing questions. If MikeKilic's answer resolved your original problem, you should mark his answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to retrieve the token from the given SA you can simply execute:

```
kubectl get secret $(kubectl get sa <sa-name> -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}' -n <namespace>) -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' -n <namespace> | base64 --decode
```

Feel free to remove the `| base64 --decode` if you don't want to decode. Just as a side node, this command might need to be amended depending on the type of secret, however for your use-case this should work

Once you have your value you can execute curl commands, such as:

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X GET "https://<KUBE-API-IP>:6443/api/v1/nodes"
```

Comment: I tested the commands. Here is the output: https://pastebin.com/xC0i4xwg For some reason the secret is not created. Any idea why?

Comment: @MikeKilic service account tokens are not created automatically in recent versions of kubernetes. See the link in my comment on the question.

Comment: @larsks thanks for the info, I'm currently running 1.22 privately. But it seems like the docs aren't up to date either. Just scraped quickly through the docs, couldn't find that particular info.