# Cannot create service account in Kubernetes v1.25.5

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a service account in Kubernetes v1.25.5 using this tutorial https://devopscube.com/kubernetes-api-access-service-account/

Full log:

```
root@node1:~# kubectl create namespace devops-tools
namespace/devops-tools created
root@node1:~# kubectl create serviceaccount api-service-account -n devops-tools
serviceaccount/api-service-account created
root@node1:~# cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: api-service-account
  namespace: devops-tools
EOF
Warning: resource serviceaccounts/api-service-account is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
serviceaccount/api-service-account configured
root@node1:~# cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: api-cluster-role
  namespace: devops-tools
rules:
  - apiGroups:
        - ""
        - apps
        - autoscaling
        - batch
        - extensions
        - policy
        - rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    resources:
      - pods
      - componentstatuses
      - configmaps
      - daemonsets
      - deployments
      - events
      - endpoints
EOF verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/api-cluster-role created
root@node1:~# kubectl api-resources
NAME                              SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION                             NAMESPACED   KIND
bindings                                       v1                                     true         Binding
componentstatuses                 cs           v1                                     false        ComponentStatus
configmaps                        cm           v1                                     true         ConfigMap
endpoints                         ep           v1                                     true         Endpoints
events                            ev           v1                                     true         Event
limitranges                       limits       v1                                     true         LimitRange
namespaces                        ns           v1                                     false        Namespace
nodes                             no           v1                                     false        Node
persistentvolumeclaims            pvc          v1                                     true         PersistentVolumeClaim
persistentvolumes                 pv           v1                                     false        PersistentVolume
pods                              po           v1                                     true         Pod
podtemplates                                   v1                                     true         PodTemplate
replicationcontrollers            rc           v1                                     true         ReplicationController
resourcequotas                    quota        v1                                     true         ResourceQuota
secrets                                        v1                                     true         Secret
serviceaccounts                   sa           v1                                     true         ServiceAccount
services                          svc          v1                                     true         Service
mutatingwebhookconfigurations                  admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1        false        MutatingWebhookConfiguration
validatingwebhookconfigurations                admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1        false        ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
customresourcedefinitions         crd,crds     apiextensions.k8s.io/v1                false        CustomResourceDefinition
apiservices                                    apiregistration.k8s.io/v1              false        APIService
controllerrevisions                            apps/v1                                true         ControllerRevision
daemonsets                        ds           apps/v1                                true         DaemonSet
deployments                       deploy       apps/v1                                true         Deployment
replicasets                       rs           apps/v1                                true         ReplicaSet
statefulsets                      sts          apps/v1                                true         StatefulSet
tokenreviews                                   authentication.k8s.io/v1               false        TokenReview
localsubjectaccessreviews                      authorization.k8s.io/v1                true         LocalSubjectAccessReview
selfsubjectaccessreviews                       authorization.k8s.io/v1                false        SelfSubjectAccessReview
selfsubjectrulesreviews                        authorization.k8s.io/v1                false        SelfSubjectRulesReview
subjectaccessreviews                           authorization.k8s.io/v1                false        SubjectAccessReview
horizontalpodautoscalers          hpa          autoscaling/v2                         true         HorizontalPodAutoscaler
cronjobs                          cj           batch/v1                               true         CronJob
jobs                                           batch/v1                               true         Job
certificatesigningrequests        csr          certificates.k8s.io/v1                 false        CertificateSigningRequest
leases                                         coordination.k8s.io/v1                 true         Lease
bgpconfigurations                              crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        BGPConfiguration
bgppeers                                       crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        BGPPeer
blockaffinities                                crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        BlockAffinity
caliconodestatuses                             crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        CalicoNodeStatus
clusterinformations                            crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        ClusterInformation
felixconfigurations                            crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        FelixConfiguration
globalnetworkpolicies                          crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        GlobalNetworkPolicy
globalnetworksets                              crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        GlobalNetworkSet
hostendpoints                                  crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        HostEndpoint
ipamblocks                                     crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        IPAMBlock
ipamconfigs                                    crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        IPAMConfig
ipamhandles                                    crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        IPAMHandle
ippools                                        crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        IPPool
ipreservations                                 crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        IPReservation
kubecontrollersconfigurations                  crd.projectcalico.org/v1               false        KubeControllersConfiguration
networkpolicies                                crd.projectcalico.org/v1               true         NetworkPolicy
networksets                                    crd.projectcalico.org/v1               true         NetworkSet
endpointslices                                 discovery.k8s.io/v1                    true         EndpointSlice
events                            ev           events.k8s.io/v1                       true         Event
flowschemas                                    flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta2   false        FlowSchema
prioritylevelconfigurations                    flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta2   false        PriorityLevelConfiguration
ingressclasses                                 networking.k8s.io/v1                   false        IngressClass
ingresses                         ing          networking.k8s.io/v1                   true         Ingress
networkpolicies                   netpol       networking.k8s.io/v1                   true         NetworkPolicy
runtimeclasses                                 node.k8s.io/v1                         false        RuntimeClass
poddisruptionbudgets              pdb          policy/v1                              true         PodDisruptionBudget
clusterrolebindings                            rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           false        ClusterRoleBinding
clusterroles                                   rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           false        ClusterRole
rolebindings                                   rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           true         RoleBinding
roles                                          rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1           true         Role
priorityclasses                   pc           scheduling.k8s.io/v1                   false        PriorityClass
csidrivers                                     storage.k8s.io/v1                      false        CSIDriver
csinodes                                       storage.k8s.io/v1                      false        CSINode
csistoragecapacities                           storage.k8s.io/v1                      true         CSIStorageCapacity
storageclasses                    sc           storage.k8s.io/v1                      false        StorageClass
volumeattachments                              storage.k8s.io/v1                      false        VolumeAttachment
root@node1:~# cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: api-cluster-role-binding
subjects:
- namespace: devops-tools
  kind: ServiceAccount
  name: api-service-account
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: api-cluster-role
EOF
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/api-cluster-role-binding created
root@node1:~# kubectl auth can-i get pods --as=system:serviceaccount:devops-tools:api-service-account
yes
root@node1:~# kubectl auth can-i delete deployments --as=system:serviceaccount:devops-tools:api-service-account
yes
root@node1:~# kubectl get serviceaccount api-service-account  -o=jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}' -n devops-tools
root@node1:~#
root@node1:~# kubectl get secrets  api-service-account-token-pgtrr  -o=jsonpath='{.data.token}' -n devops-tools | base64 -D
base64: invalid option -- 'D'
Try 'base64 --help' for more information.
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "api-service-account-token-pgtrr" not found
root@node1:~# kubectl get endpoints | grep kubernetes
kubernetes   192.168.1.24:6443   3d22h
```

As you can see I should get the token secret but I get empty result. Do you know what should be the correct step?

Comment: Are you having the same problem as in [Service account secret is not listed. How to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256006/service-account-secret-is-not-listed-how-to-fix-it)  Can you trim down the long console output to a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blog you are following is from **June 5, 2021** might be using the old k8s release, while in **2022-12-08** **1.24** relased and you are using the **1.25**

In **1.24** Kubernetes release there is change which don't auto crate the secret when you are creating the **ServiceAccount**.

**Steps to follow**

If you want to create the secret you can create it with

```
kubectl create sa <Service account name>
```

Create a YAML file with below and update the name and Service Account name

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: token-secret
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "<Service Account name>"
```

`kubectl apply -f <File created above>.yaml`

**Extra option**

You can also use the kubectl in case just want to create the Token

```
kubectl create token jwt-tk --duration=999999h
```

**Few ref**

[Release note](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.24.md) & [Pull request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/108309)

Comment: Can you paste the complete sequence of commands please?